# Convert a list of maps by the values of the maps [clojure]

Tags: list, dictionary, data-structures, clojure

I have a list filled with many maps (all of them have the same key), like this:

```
({:a 1} {:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 2})
```

I would like to convert it to a map that stores the occurrence of the value of each map. For exemple, the list above should return the following map:

```
{:1 2, :2 3, :3 1}
```

Any ideas on how can i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```clj
(def m '({:a 1} {:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 2}))

(frequencies (map :a m)) ;; => {1 2, 2 3, 3 1}
```

Note the keys of the result are not keywords, as that would be an odd thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn maps->freqs
  [maps]
  (frequencies
    (for [m maps]
      (second (first m)))))

(dotest
  (let [data (quote
               ({:a 1} {:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 2}))]
    (is= (maps->freqs data)
      {1 2, 2 3, 3 1})))
```

The above uses my favorite template project.  The best technique is to build it up slowely:

```
(defn maps->freqs
  [maps]
  (for [m maps]
    (first m)))
```

then `(spyx-pretty (maps->freqs data))` produces

```
(maps->freqs data) => 
[[:a 1] [:a 1] [:a 2] [:a 2] [:a 3] [:a 2]]
```

modify it:

```
(defn maps->freqs
  [maps]
  (for [m maps]
    (second (first m))))
```

with result

```
(maps->freqs data) => 
[1 1 2 2 3 2]
```

Then use `frequencies` to get the final result.

Please be sure to read the [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet!